# Get a single variable and a single function from a module without executing the module?

Tags: python, variables, import

I am new to python, so please forgive me.

I have a module: **beep.py**, which contains a variable: **p** (contains a string) and function: **ps**. I need to access both of these from a module: **boop**, and use them there.

My problem is, if I try writing `import beep` in **boop**, then **beep** runs all of it's code. Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: How is `beep` laid out? Do you have a `main()` function, and/or use `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

Answer (score 2):

Python executes all top level instructions when a module is imported. Well behaved modules that are intended to be importable should limit what they do with top level code. - they may run code at import, but it should not have side effects. It is common to use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom to have a python module that can run as a script and as a imported module (see example).

If `import beep` causes problems, then either it was not designed to be imported or is is poorly written and needs to be fixed.

```
print 'i always run'

def fctn():
    print 'i run when called'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'i run if called as a script but not if imported as a module'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python always evaluates the file that you import, so if you have some code outside a function or class, it will be executed. As [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney)  says you can protect the imported file using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I've create the full example here: https://gist.github.com/carlosvin/d9a1eb978fac226dbbe9